# Detect What Causing Oracle's Server CPU Usage 100%

Tags: oracle

Hello I'm new to Oracle.

I got a Problem where my Oracle DB server resource between 11:06-11:24 is suddenly at max. Of course it is because Oracle Database process consume 99.1% usage.

[Oracle 100% Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRkHq.png)

When I track using my monitor tools, between 5 minutes range (11:05-11:10), it shown that this statement:

```
Begin PKG_NEW_UPDATER.INS_OUTLET_DATA_SYNC(:v0, :v1, :v2, :v3, :v4); End;
```

consume as follows:

- CPU time:44 min 27.3 s
- Wait time: 6 h 17 min 54.9 s
- Buffer gets: 444M
- Executions: 9.72 k
- Processed rows: 9.72 k

Could we assume that statement caused the CPU usage become 100% ?

And if it is true, is there any documentation about it so I could show to my team?

Thank you in advance.

Finding what cause CPU high

Answer (score 0):

Every monitoring tool is of course unique, so what those numbers mean depends on the tool. Given they are reporting 6 hours of wait time I doubt those numbers cover only 5 minutes of clock time, unless you had 70-80 processes running this concurrently, but that would also report a similarly high CPU number.

If you have access to the oracle owner OS account on the server, you can run an AWR report in SQL Plus: `@?/rdbms/admin/awrrpt`

If you need the ability to drill down and customize your search and are willing to get a bit more in the weeds, then I suggest using ASH (this is where an AWR report gets its data). Query `v$active_session_history` to find out who/what used most CPU during that time:

```
 SELECT user_id,module,plsql_object_id,plsql_subprogram_id,sql_id,COUNT(*) cpu_secs
   FROM v$active_session_history
  WHERE event IS NULL -- on CPU
    AND sample_time BETWEEN TO_DATE('08/08/2023 11:06:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('08/08/2023 11:24:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
 GROUP BY user_id,module,plsql_object_id,plsql_subprogram_id,sql_id
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

The number of rows is the estimated # of seconds, in this case, on CPU. So by exchanging or adding group by dimensions and requerying, you can drill down on what was contributing the most to CPU at that time. If it's been more than an hour or so you might not have the data in this view anymore, as it gets flushed by AWR. If that's the case, switch to the longer-term permanent table, but multiply the rows by 10 to get seconds since it only records 1 out of 10 of the original samples:

```
 SELECT user_id,module,plsql_object_id,plsql_subprogram_id,sql_id,COUNT(*)*10 cpu_secs
   FROM dba_hist_active_sess_history
  WHERE event IS NULL -- on CPU
    AND sample_time BETWEEN TO_DATE('08/08/2023 11:06:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('08/08/2023 11:24:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
 GROUP BY user_id,module,plsql_object_id,plsql_subprogram_id,sql_id
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

You can look up the names for some of the numeric IDs in the output using `dba_users`, `dba_objects`, `dba_procedures`, etc.

If most of your time shows a `plsql_object_id` but no `sql_id`, then it's PL/SQL execution (e.g. maybe a loop without a sleep or something) that's the issue. If you see both, then it's a SQL problem which your procedure just happens to be initiating and attention should be on the SQL itself more than the procedure. Unless of course the issue is the SQL is getting executed too often, which could lead you to looking at the PL/SQL code that runs it.